# Arrow point to finger in Corona SDK?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I asked a similar question like this earlier, but I was not specific on what I wanted. There is a picture of an arrow, and when it is touched and your finger moves around, I want the arrow to scale up and down and rotate so the pointer end of the arrow is at your finger, and the middle of the arrow always stays where it is (the arrow moves around the center point). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the angle between the arrow's x, y and the touch event's x. y something like this:

```
local tan = math.abs(arrow.y-event.y) / math.abs(arrow.x-event.x);
local atan = math.atan(tan); -- (result in radians)
local angle = atan * 180 / math.pi; -- converted to degrees
arrow.rotation = angle
```

Then to size the arrow, you need to save the original size of the arrow, probably keeping track of the longest side:

```
local arrowLength = 100 -- for instance
local dX = event.x - arrow.x
local dy = event.y - arrow.y
local distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
local scale = distance / arrowLength
arrow:scale(scale, scale)
```

This code is untested and may need tweaked, but it should get you started.

Comment: How would I get this to scale and rotate in real time? I inserted it into a touch event, but it only scales up once and rotates slightly with every click. Sorry for all the questions, but this is the last piece I need to finish my test app!

Comment: The touch event has a "moved" phase and this is where you would put this code.  Make sure to study the touch-drag sample project.